# Split the video into images in java

Tags: java, image, video

I want to split the video into images using Java. Then, I want to convert the images into bytes. I tried finding a solution, but was not able to solve it up.

Can anyone let me know the solution or example code of the same?

Thanks

Comment: Could you at least give us the code you tried and that didn't work? We're here to help you solve specific problems, not to do all the work for you.

Comment: When you say split the video, do you mean that you want to extract the frames from the video? What exactly do you want as the output from converting the images to bytes, an array of bytes?

Comment: @richard : I wanted to stream video from my pc to android and for that reason I am trying to build server which can convert video to bytes so that I can stream those bytes from network.

Comment: @talnicolas : sir, i dont want anyone to do all work for me. just guidance of knowledge of some steps will be sufficient. thanks

Comment: If you don't need to manipulate the video before streaming it, the solution I posted below may work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadcast the video via an [RTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) stream from the PC. Use the [Daroon](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.daroonsoft.player&hl=en) player on the Android to play the video.